# how can i use Rest Sharp API put method

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

hey i am trying to use put method like the code below. i need have a body  like this

```
{
  "lines": [
    {
      "lineId": 300198921,
      "quantity": 1
    }],
  "params": {
  },
  "status": "Picking"
}
```

i run the request on talend API there is no problem but in c# always getting an error

```
public static void TrendyolDurumGüncelle()
        {
            client = new RestClient("https://api.trendyol.com/sapigw/suppliers/{supplierId}/shipment-packages/{Id}");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(TrendyolUserName, TrendyolPassword);

            request = new RestRequest("https://api.trendyol.com/sapigw/suppliers/{supplierId}/shipment-packages/{Id}", Method.PUT);
            request.AddUrlSegment("supplierId", TrendyolMerchantId);
            request.AddUrlSegment("Id", "173657633");



            var body = new { lines = new {lineId = "300198921", quantity = 3 } , @params = new { } ,status = "Picking" }; 

            request.AddJsonBody(body); 

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;



        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample json `lines` property is array, so try:

```
var body = new 
{
    lines = new[] { new { lineId = "300198921", quantity = 3 } } ,
    @params = new { } ,
    status = "Picking" 
};
```